# How do i fix the NoClassDefFoundError and DexPath errors

Tags: android

I'm quite a new Android developer. I' working on a project with a few other guys and we use GitHub to collaborate. The particular app that gives me an error doesn't run on any of the other guys phones, so I've been given the task to fix it. Here is the problem: when i run the app on my phone, it crashes... Here is the error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 Failed resolution of: Lcom/crashlytics/android/Crashlytics;
```

and the second error on the logcat is:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics"
 on path: DexPathList[[dex fil
```

e...

I tried searching online but the suggestion to enable Multidex in the gradle folder didn't seem to help.

Thanx

---

This is my gradle file...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/gen_approx_cyrillic.txt'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aftarobot.assocbuilder"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    //    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
            {
                exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            })
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //    compile project(path: ':aftarobotbackend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    //    compile project(path: ':xbackend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile project(':aftarobotlibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: I have appended the gradle file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys thanx for contributing. I got it fixed. I ended up going to the master branch of GitHub and copying that version of the manifest and it worked. I didn't have to change anything in the gradle file